# Trying to put alternative to noscript to work; fine but not in a mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, mobile, noscript

I recently discovered a gracefully simple way to display a message if the agent has javascript disabled, and it works great -- on my laptop..!

I tested it out on mobile safari, it's not working. Is there any reason for it not to? I took into account these things when writing my code:

1. The markup/dom actually loading/registering, so I put a script tag after the ending tag of my div
2. Any type of reason why it shouldn't work right away, so I made use of the setTimeout function and had it wait 100 ms
3. Used jquery just incase the good old dom lookup and style modification stuff didn't perform as well/correctly

My code:

```
<div id="enable-js">
        <div id="content-container">
            <div id="text_wrapper">
                <p>For the best experience, please <a href="http://www.activatejavascript.org/">enable
                    javascript</a>.
                    If your browser is not capable of using javascript,
                    please considering getting a <a href="http://alternativebrowseralliance.com/browsers.html">better
                        browser</a>.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#enable-js').hide(); //hide area if scripts enabled
            }, 100);
        })();
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance, guys.

EDIT:

I confirmed the problem is not with Webkit; as well as the fact that it makes no difference starting it off with a self-invoking anonymous function or by placing the hiding code in window.onload as opposed to after the div's closing tag.

EDIT2:

Confirmed that doing document.getElementById and setting display to none isn't working either! What is going on...

Comment: Why not `<noscript>`? And have you tried putting your `.hide()` functionality in the document ready?

Comment: noscript makes it difficult to sometimes validate under the strict doctype; and it makes more sense to just present a noscript message, and put in a script to hide it. If scripts are enabled, it will effectively hide the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the load() event and if that doesn't work $(document).ready() is almost absolutely sure to do what you want.

You should try using a webkit browser on your computer and see if it isn't a webkit problem.

Comment: I have just confirmed that the problem is not with webkit. The idea is hide the div as soon as it's done loading as opposed to the entire document, so that the user doesn't see any flickering, or worse, thinks there's a glitch in the page.

Comment: What about ready()? and last thing I can suggest is instead of hide()try applying "display: none" or "visibility: hidden" and check your stylesheet maybe it a bug in mobile webkit

Answer (score 0):

Edit: whole new idea.

It could be that mobile safari doesn't support desktop jquery.

You could either try jQuery mobile. Or this:

```
    (function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#enable-js').css({'display':'none'}); //hide area if scripts enabled
        }, 100);
    })();
```

Comment: No, I just tested that way, there's no difference.

Comment: It's just a self-invoking anonymous function, good for cleaning up scope and such.

Comment: No, i'm afraid your wrong again. I just tested .css as well as just plain doing document.getElementById('enable-js').style.display = 'none'; and it still isn't working.